# Blank page appearing after saving page

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to display some posts in a builder so I created a shortcode of that by following steps
1) created a file in wp-content and added a function which displays posts
2) created a following shortcode in function.php

```
include(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/Divi/custom_shortcodes/show_packages_func.php');

add_shortcode( 'display_packages', 'display_tour_packages' );
```

After using these shortcodes, when I save a page (as an example `/wp-admin/post.php?post=1517&action=edit` ), it converts or redirects to `/wp-admin/post.php` with no content (blank white page).

Also when I try to install plugns, they failed. WHen I activate plugins, the page displays blank page without activating plugin.

Is there a valid reason of this?

Edit: I find many posts regarding custom shortcode with visual composer and no one complained about any break in code, or any kind of problem.

EDIT: Researched and retried more:

The problem might be WP_query(), I have WP File manager installed but it was not responding. I added wp_reset_query() in both files (where I am using wp_query() ) which let File manager working but still pages and plugins are displaying white pages and save/activate